# C++ вызов методов класса A в классе B и наоборот

Tags: c++, ооп

```
class A
{
public:
   void foo(){B b; b.foo();}
}


class B
{
public:
   void foo(){A a; a.foo();}
}
```

Возможно ли в C++ сделать подобное?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В каком смысле *возможно*?

Чтоб скомпилировалось? запросто:

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo();
};

class B
{
public:
    void foo();
};

void A::foo(){B b; b.foo();}
void B::foo(){A a; a.foo();}
```

Чтоб работало? вряд ли - получается бесконечная рекурсия...

Раз пошел вопрос о разделении на заголовочные файлы...

**a_d.hpp**

```
#pragma once

class A
{
public:
    void foo();
};
```

**b_d.hpp**

```
#pragma once

class B
{
public:
    void foo();
};
```

**a_i.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "a_d.hpp"
#include "b_d.hpp"

void A::foo(){B b; b.foo();}
```

**b_i.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "a_d.hpp"
#include "b_d.hpp"

void B::foo(){A a; a.foo();}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "a_i.hpp"
#include "b_i.hpp"

int main()
{
    A a; a.foo();
    B b; b.foo();
}
```

Comment: Если этот код разделить по заголовкам - то не работает. Даже учитывая что есть #pragma once

Comment: Да работает, надо только правильно разделить объявление и *реализацию*...

Comment: Я видел кто-то пишет в .h файлах весь код, и имеет только 1 .cpp в таком случае  уже не так всё просто.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков См. дополненный ответ.